# Accessing the vibration function in Windows 8 WinRT?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is there an WinRT API in Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8 to use the vibration function?

Comment: You mean, make the device vibrate?

Comment: Yes, to make the device vibrate.

Comment: Don't ask questions based on leak unfinished software.

Answer (score 4):

Try this: (Only works on Windows Phone!)

```
var vibrationTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification.VibrationDevice.GetDefault().Vibrate(vibrationTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

The leaked docs seem to mention the [Microsoft.Devices.VibrateController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.vibratecontroller%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class being available both in WP7 and WP8. I don't think there is something like that in WinRT though. I think tablets usually don't have a vibrator? Seems to be more like a feature of a phone that you might keep silenced in your pocket.

Some articles on [vibrations](http://blog.xyzzer.me/tag/vibrate/)

Comment: A Windows Phone 8 application, created in Visual Studio 2012 RC, does not have access to that API. That and the whole of Windows Phone 7 API, is unavailable. It's WinPRT all the way.

Comment: I would not judge it based on unfinished APIs though. You can create an app targeting WP7 and it will work on WP8. If the new APIs don't include the VibrateController now - they could still be added by the time the SDK is made public.

Answer (score 0):

We do have one for Windows Phone 8 and 7 , but we don't have for WinRT tablets

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VibrateController or VibrationDevice  class to achieve vibration effect in your Windows Phone apps.

Refer http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paraswadehra/archive/2014/06/25/how-to-make-your-windows-phone-app-vibrate.aspx for details.